# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve @shared/revediabutton/revediabutton'

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm using React 18 and Vs Code to build UI Library (created using create react app with typescript), in that i have created shared folder inside the src folder, to minimise the path import i have added alias in the tsconsifg file

```
"baseUrl": ".",
  "paths": {
    "@shared/*": ["./src/shared/*"]
  },
```

but after adding this, i'm getting an error like
**Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@shared/revediabutton/revediabutton' in '/Users/murugan/Documents/Learning React/react-data-grid/src/component/button'**

```
import RevediaStack from '@shared/revediaStack/revediaStack';
import RevediaButton from '@shared/revediabutton/revediabutton';
```

the import looks likes above
and the folder structure below

[image]

Please help me to resolve this